# Checkbox validation in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp

How do I create validation for checkbox is should select in `cakephp 3.0`

In `cakephp 2.x` the validation is like:

```
'accept_terms' => array(
        'rule' => array('comparison', '!=', 0),
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'You must agree to the terms',
        'on' => 'create',
    ),
```

I want to convert it to `cakephp 3.x`.

Comment: Have you read the official docs on [validation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html)?

Answer (score 2):

In CakePHP 3.x

**Form**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('username'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('password'); ?>
...
<?= $this->Form->control('term_and_conditions'); ?>
<?= $this->Form->submit(__('Save')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

**Model:** the **Validator::equals($field, $value, $message = null, $when = null)** allows you to check if a checkbox is checked

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    ...
    $validator
        ->boolean('term_and_conditions')
        ->requirePresence('term_and_conditions', 'create')
        ->equals('term_and_conditions', true);
    ...

    return $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no special rule for validating a checkbox. What you want to do is validate that the field is `notEmpty` on `create`:-

```
$validator
    ->requirePresence('accept_terms')
    ->notEmpty('accept_terms', 'You must agree to the terms', 'create');
```

This can be found in the [official docs on Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#allowing-empty-fields). The full list of available validation rules can be [found in the API docs](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can make with custom method to make validate for your checkbox. I do like this. This is ok to me.

```
 public function validationBooking(Validator $validator)
    {

        $validator->add('accept_terms', 'custom', [
            'rule' => [$this, 'AcceptTerm'],
            'message' => 'You must agreed Term and Condition'
        ]);
        return $validator;
    }
        //make function
        public function AcceptTerm($value,$context){
                if($context['data']['accept_terms']==1)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a checkbox is checked via the `requirePresence`-Validation-Method.

In your model:

```
$validator
        ->boolean('accept_legalnotice')
        ->requirePresence('accept_legalnotice', true, 'You have to accept.');
```

To get this work, you need to disable the hidden field for the checkbox that is generated by the form-helper.

In your view:

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('accept_legalnotice', ['hiddenField' => false]);
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls